# Pitch detection for multiple voices

Tags: music, audio

I greatly enjoy singing a cappella music with multiple parts (usually 4, but in principle, any number of parts between 2 and 8). It's less enjoyable when we're singing out of tune. We are amateurs: we can usually hear when we're out of tune, but often we can't tell *why*.

Pitch detection software can help with this: you feed it a recording and it displays the exact pitch of the sound against a particular scale of notes you're supposed to be using. A great example is [Tartini](http://miracle.otago.ac.nz/tartini/):

1. It is pretty good at detecting the pitch of a singing voice correctly.
2. It runs on my Ubuntu Linux box at home, as well as on Windows.
3. It is inexpensive (completely free, in fact).
4. It visualizes pitch in intuitive ways.
5. It supports various tuning systems, not just equal temperament.
6. It works in real time, plotting the pitch as the sound is being produced.

However, it has one big limitation: it only detects a single pitch, not the pitches of *all* voices in multipart music.

Is there any pitch detection software that supports *multiple* parts? If any such software exists, how close does it come to meeting the above list of properties?

Comment: Take a look at http://nastechservices.com/MidiAnalysis.html - I haven't tried the software described so can not reasonably make this an answer.

Comment: Doesn't that take MIDI files as input?  What I need is (basically) MIDI *output* from recorded audio.

Comment: That link also links onward to the integrated Spectratune(Plus) which takes in .wav or live sounds...

Comment: I did try it, but the interface was really confusing. and I couldn't figure out whether it could do what I want. I suppose it's time to try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I was pointed to this question after answering another, newer question on a similar topic, so this is almost verbatim from my own answer there…

It wasn't possible when this question was first asked, but has been added in later revisions.

---

[Melodyne](https://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne) by Celemony has long been the acknowledged leader in this. It is capable of full polyphonic analysis, not just one or two parts. Once it's analysed, you can then individually edit any of the parts & recombine them into a new re-tuned/re-timed audio file.

[image]

It is not particularly cheap - €700 for the full version, €99 for the basic, but you don't get the polyphonic analysis until the €400 version & above.
macOS & Windows-compatible.