# Voice/pitch analyzer for two voices

Tags: audio, music, voice

This app can display the pitch of one voice/sound at a time: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tadaoyamaoka.vocalpitchmonitor

[image]

It gets messy however if there is more than one sound. I am looking for an app similar to this one, which can display the pitch of two voices/sounds simultaneously. It should have the musical notes labeled on the graph, as the screenshot above. Does anyone know of any such app? Paid/unpaid or mobile/desktop, anything works.

I've tried using a more serious spectrum analyzer, such as this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.intoorbit.spectrum

However it shows too much information, and doesn't display the notes of the (or a) scale.

Answer (score 1):

[Melodyne](https://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne) by Celemony has long been the acknowledged leader in this. It is capable of full polyphonic analysis, not just one or two parts. Once it's analysed, you can then individually edit any of the parts & recombine them into a new re-tuned/re-timed audio file.

[image]

It is not particularly cheap - €700 for the full version, €99 for the basic, but you don't get the polyphonic analysis until the €400 version & above.
macOS & Windows-compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I cannot tell from the website, does it allow seeing the notes in real time? I get the impression one must analyze an existing recording to see the notes

Comment: You might also consider posting Melodyne as an answer to this old question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11644/pitch-detection-for-multiple-voices

Comment: It does need processing time. TBH, I've only ever used it as a plugin inside a DAW, where it's always 'after the fact'. The standalone version *might* be able to do real-time from input, but it feels like a pretty heavy process to do that on a full multi-track.